# How to delete duplicates from an arraylist

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to delete duplicates from arraylist :

```
public static List<List<String>> bigList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i++) {
        bigList.get(i).stream()
            .map(str -> new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(","))))
            .distinct()
            .map(set -> set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

When executing the code, I still get duplicates in my list.
I want to delete the duplicates from bigList and bigList.get(i).

Comment: You are not assigning the result of `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to anything. So you are constructing a new list, which is just immediately thrown away.

Comment: I don't really understand what I should do exactly? declare new arraylist and use it?

Comment: @Michael Why don’t you make an Answer of your Comments?

Comment: @LSoft Wrap your line with `bigList.set( i , … )` to replace the old list with the new list.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted has anything to do with doubles.

Comment: Your `for` loop will not run at all; you do `bigList = new ArrayList<>()` and you loop on `i < bigList.size()` — well, bigList.size() is zero so there will be no iterations.

Comment: @LouisWasserman re-reading the question I think it is about duplicate entries ("doubles") in the lists, not vars of type `double`

Comment: @Basil your solution worked thanks.

Comment: @LSoft You are encouraged on Stack Overflow to write and accept your own Answer.

Comment: Why is this Question closed?

Comment: @BasilBourque instead of looping and calling `get`, followed by calling `set`, it’s much simpler to use `bigList.replaceAll(list -> list.stream()….collect(Collectors.toList()));` Alternatively, the OP could truly remove the duplicates from the lists, instead of creating new lists.

Comment: @BasilBourque you can vote for reopening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Capture the new list

Your code creates a new list each time through the `for` loop. But the new list is immediately lost, headed for garbage collection. You neglected to capture a reference to that newly-created list.

So, the solution is: Replace the old list stored as an element in the outer list with the new list. Wrap your stream line with `bigList.set( i , … )`.

```
public static List< List< String > > bigList = new ArrayList<>(); // A list of lists of strings.
…
    for (int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i++) {
        bigList.set( 
            i ,       // Index of outer list, where the new list should go.
            bigList   
            .get(i)
            .stream()
            .map( str -> new LinkedHashSet<>( Arrays.asList( str.split( "," ) ) ) )
            .distinct()
            .map( set -> set.stream().collect( Collectors.joining( "," ) ) )
            .collect( Collectors.toList() )  // Produce a new list. Stored in place of the old list.
        ) ;
    }
```

For clarity, break the code into separate lines.

```
public static List< List< String > > bigList = new ArrayList<>(); // A list of lists of strings.
…
    for (int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i++) {
        List< String > oldList = bigList.get( i ) ;
        List< String > newList = 
            oldList
            .stream()
            .map( str -> new LinkedHashSet<>( Arrays.asList( str.split( "," ) ) ) )
            .distinct()
            .map( set -> set.stream().collect( Collectors.joining( "," ) ) )
            .collect( Collectors.toList() )  // Produce a new list. Stored in place of the old list.
        ) ;
        bigList.set( i , newList ) ;  // Replace the old list with the newly-created list.
    }
```